# sprintf for format concatenation using variable

Tags: c

I can use macro to concatenate string using sprintf like below:

```c
#define ATTR_FORMAT "\"%s\":\"%s\""
#define ATTR_FORMAT_SET "\"%s\":[%s]"

sprintf(demoStr, "{" ATTR_FORMAT "}", "Hello", "world");
printf("demoStr=%s\n", demoStr);
```

I got the correct output: `demoStr={"Hello":"world"}`.

but when I assign the macro to a variable like below:

```c
#define ATTR_FORMAT "\"%s\":\"%s\""
#define ATTR_FORMAT_SET "\"%s\":[%s]"

const char *fmt = NULL;
int iTest = 1;
if (iTest == 1) {
    fmt = ATTR_FORMAT;
} else {
    fmt = ATTR_FORMAT_SET;
}

sprintf(demoStr, "{" fmt "}", "Hello", "world");
printf("demoStr=%s\n", demoStr);
```

I expect the output of `demoStr={"Hello":"world"}`.

But when i compile the code using gcc, i got below error:

```
`error: expected ')' before 'fmt'`
```

How can solve this problem, could anyone give me a hint or show me some code?

Comment: Don't do that; instead have `fmt = "{" ATTR_FORMAT "}";` etc.

Comment: according to your suggestion, i have tried, same error.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your answers. Now it correctly `demoStr={"Hello":"world"}`.